# Blue boxes aroud the questions - what are they for?

Tags: support

It seems like a new feature was added to the PMSE site, but I can not found it's meaning. Some questions are surrounded by a light blue box. What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is highlighting questions with tags that are in your favorite tags.  If you haven't manually added any favorite tags, the system will detect when you have a certain level of activity in a tag and infer one for you.  If you manually add a favorite tag, the system will not infer a tag for you.

You can customize your favorite (and ignored tags) in [your profile](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/927/bartosz-rakowski?tab=prefs).  You can also customize these settings in the right sidebar of the homepage and the /questions listing.

So, if you would prefer not to have any questions highlighted, you can simply add a nonsense "tag" to your favorites.  Perhaps [unicorn](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicorn)? (:

Comment: I like the idea of using "null" to specify no tags. But I'd imagine on a lot of the technical sites there may in fact actually be a tag called `null`, so maybe that might not work. Maybe `nonsense` would work better for me :)  Or I could use unicorn, unless someone creates a site about mythical creatures...